# Numpy: reshape uneven 1D array to 2D array for byte plotting

Tags: numpy, reshape

This might be too easy for everyone, but as I mentioned in the subject, is there a way to reshape an uneven 1D numpy array to 2D numpy array?
When I say uneven 1D array, the shape is **(34191,)** and this came from reading a binary file using **np.fromfile**

The actual thing that I'm trying to do here is actually display/plot the binary files i'm reading as images (like a byte plot).
So read the file as 1D numpy array, convert it to 2D array, display/plot/save it as grey scale image.

Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: What dimensions do you expect the images to have?

Comment: I want to try with 64x64 first. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I think I don't really get what exactly you want. You have 34191 values and want to arange them in a 2D grid, right? But if the grid is only 64x64 the values are obvoiously not going to fit. I think I haven't understood the problem corretly, can you try to clarify?

Comment: As mentioned, i want to do a byte plot. That is, each byte of my binary file, to be treated as a pixel, and plotted/displayed/saved as an image. So its like the binary hex viewers, but I want to save the visualization of the binary file to as an image of nxm size

Comment: `arr[:n*m].reshape(n,m)` will convert it to a 2d array, provided `n*m` is less than the total length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting the question correctly, you have a 1D array, and you want to display it as an image, but you don't know *a priori* what shape it should be.

This function finds the 'squarest' shape (i.e. the two factors closest in value) of a number.

```
import numpy as np

def closest_factor_pair(x: int) -> tuple:
    """
    Tries to find the pair of factors of x, i.e. the
    closest integers to the square root of x.

    Example
    >>> closest_factor_pair(34191)
    (131, 261)
    """
    for i in range(int(np.sqrt(x)), 0, -1):
        if x % i == 0:
            return i, int(x/i)
    return None
```

We could use it to guess the size of your array and display it:

```
>>> size = 34191
>>> shape = closest_factor_pair(size)
(131, 261)
```

If you have your array, you can reshape it and display:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.random.random(size)
plt.matshow(arr.reshape(shape))
```

Which gives:

[image: image of random numbers formed from 1D array]

Comment: Thanks a lot kwinkunks. Exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: No worries @jaysonpryde. It occurs to me that you will need to try reshaping with both `(a, b)` and `(b, a)` to see which one is more 'organized'. Maybe you can figure out a way to tell automatically which is correct / best, depending on your data.